# Which errors trigger "[HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP request" in PHP SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I've written a php script that does a number of SOAP requests. Every once in a while a request fails with `[HTTP] Failed Sending HTTP SOAP request` error. I cannot find anywhere which errors cause this exception. Anyone has any experience with this?

example code: https://pastebin.com/uk5L9QTA

The class in the pastebin is instantiated, then `getArticoli()` is called. In the class, omitted, there are other methods to call other soap functions.

The log signals an uncaught SoapFault at row 14. The exception is thrown only there, despite numerous other calls to various soap methods, and only sometimes. Replaying the request via curl, postman, does not produce any error. The code started to report this error a couple days ago, after a month of successful deployment. The code is run by a cronjob every hour, sometimes it fails, sometimes it runs smoothly. The same code is deployed on two other servers and not a single exception was thrown.

Thanks

Comment: Anyone who dealt with SOAP has had a cold shower like this. Some code, please. Read about **[the perfect question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)** and try to come up with a **[Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)**. People will appreciate and you are much more likely to get some real help.

Comment: yeah sorry, editing.